# Hex to integer (4 bytes)

Tags: java, android, int, hex, zigbee

I'm working with ZigBee, I receive data from a sensor of a end device, and I want to convert from hex to int. The data are from 4bytes, this information is regarding the battery, an example of what I get would be this: "00 00 00 e1" (but without blanks) and I need to pass this on to voltages, but first I think I need to pass it to int.

Anyone can help me please? I'm doing my application for Android.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Are you receiving a string (`"000000e1"`) or a byte array (`0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0xe1`)?  You'll end up using different code to process each representation into a big-endian 32-bit unsigned integer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
int n = (int)Long.parseLong(st.replaceAll("\\s+",""), 16);
```

(where st is your string) does it. Two things:

The `replaceAll` strips out any white space.

I go via the `Long` parser to circumvent `NumberFormatExceptions` for negatives

Comment: Thank you for you response, When I receive the information I have no blanks, you tell me you pass the 8 characters and with that I would transform function to int?

Comment: Your example contains whitespace so I assumed you needed to parse that. Without the spaces you can just do `int n = (int)Long.parseLong(st, 16);`, again going through `Long` to circumvent `NumberFormatExceptions` for negatives.

Answer (score 3):

Use [`Integer.parseInt()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#parseInt%28java.lang.String,%20int%29) for this:

> Parses the string argument as a signed integer in the radix specified by the second argument

Example:

```
Integer.parseInt("-FF", 16) // pass 16 to indicate an hexadecimal value
=> -255
```

Comment: Thank you for your response, then, I can use this function to get the data into int, then only I have to pass it to voltage does not?

Comment: @Despotars I don't understand your question. This function will convert from hex to int. Likewise, the function`Integer.toString()` will convert from int to hex. Use them as needed.

Answer (score 1):

```
Integer.parseInt("ff0000", 16)
```

Comment: Thank you for your response! I'm going to try it